# mailoutbox works only if last fixture

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

If I use the [mailoutbox](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#mailoutbox) fixture like this, it works:

```
def test_send_invoices_via_mail_page(user_client, invoice, mailoutbox):
    url = reverse(send_invoices_via_mail_page)
    response = user_client.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    log = LogOfInvoiceMail.objects.get(invoice=invoice)
    assert log.success, log.exception
    assert log.invoice == invoice
    assert log.exception == ''
    assert len(mailoutbox) == 1, mailoutbox
```

But if I use it like this it fails:

```
    def test_send_invoices_via_mail_page(mailoutbox, user_client, invoice):
```

Error:

```
>       assert len(mailoutbox) == 1, mailoutbox
E       AssertionError: []
E       assert 0 == 1
```

Why is the order of the arguments important here?

I am 100% sure that `mail.send_mail()` gets called in both cases, since I tested it ten times (with ten different ways).

Comment: Does it have to be *last*, or just after one (which?) of the other two? Where do the other two come from? What's under test?

Comment: Seems to be known issue since 2018: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/589